# how to Create a paramter field in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

i want to create a parameter field in crystal reports which is displayed when report runs, if user chooses "option A" data is displayed according to "option A" but if user chooses "option b", user have to choose from "option C" and "option D" which are displayed only when "Option B" is selected

Answer (score 0):

Crystal makes this very tricky (if i've interpreted your question correctly).

Ideally you need to create your own frontend to run the report (as you can have any complex logic you like).

In Crystal designer the closest you'll get will be by creating a dynamic, cascading parameter where the two tiers contain your two levels of options.

```
col1, col2
OptA, OptA
OptB, OptC
OptB, OptD
```

You'll then need to link those to your main tables or you'll end up with a mess of data.